# How can I check images loaded after I have used $.GET?

Tags: jquery, ajax, loaded

Okay so I have some code

```
$.get('results1.html', function(data) {
    $('#search-results').html(data);        
}).complete(function() {
    BlockStuffNow();    
});
```

BlockStuffNow(); is a function that operates on the images that have been loaded into #search-results, BUT it can only operate on them after they all have been loaded, how can I check to see if they have been loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple load, then run the callback function...

```
$("#search-results").load("results1.html",function(){
        $('img').load(function(){
                BlockStuffNow();
        })
});​​​​​​
```

Comment: Hey Chris, I tryed this, however it fires before the images are complete :(

Comment: $('#search-results').BlocksIt({numOfCol: 3,offsetX: 4,offsetY: 5});

thats for the function, BlocksIt basically sets the size of the division to however big the elements contained in it are, but it does that before the images are even loaded, so i was wondering maybe I could wait till the images are loaded to call that function